# How can I select some rows from all data frames in a list in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am having difficulty applying some calculations to my data frames in a list. Actually, I am failing from the very beginning, when I try to pick some rows from each data.frame.

This piece of code generates something very similar to my data, albeit I have many more and much longer data frames in my list.

```
ROI <- c("0", "1", "blank")
Red <- c(17, 48, 1.9)
Green <- c(13, 0.2, 1.1)
df1 <- data.frame(ROI, Red, Green, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1_tb <- tbl_df(df1)
ROI <- c("0", "1", "2", "3", "blank1", "blank2")
Red <- c(14, 22, 53, 11, 0.5, 0.7)
Green <- c(110, 109, 57, 11, 2, 7)
df2 <- data.frame(ROI, Red, Green, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2_tb <- tbl_df(df2)
my_list <- list(df1_tb, df2_tb)

> my_list
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
    ROI   Red Green
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0  17.0  13.0
2     1  48.0   0.2
3 blank   1.9   1.1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 6 × 3
     ROI   Red Green
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1      0  14.0   110
2      1  22.0   109
3      2  53.0    57
4      3  11.0    11
5 blank1   0.5     2
6 blank2   0.7     7
```

What I want to try is to find rows when ROI column is or contains "blank", calculate mean for these rows for each data frames, and then to subtract these values from rest of the rows.
I thought of combining `grepl` and `filter` as `filter(my_list, grepl("blank", my_list, my_list$ROI))`, but this gave me following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "list"
```

When I try to apply this approach to single elements in my list, it works;

```
> k <- filter(df2, grepl("blank", df2$ROI))
> k
     ROI Red Green
1 blank1 0.5     2
2 blank2 0.7     7
```

I also tried to use `lapply` or some nested form of it, but without success. Here, when I wanted to write something like

```
lapply(my_list, filter, grepl("blank", my_list$ROI))
```

I am not sure how I should feed `grepl` in that case though, so that it should start checking columns in each data frame, but not objects in `my_list`. 
I am not very adept in R, and I guess I am missing here which order lapply or sapply functions work. Or maybe I should change how I try to do it from the beginning...

How can I approach my problem? Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: The `lapply` attempt is close, take a look at examples of using `lapply` elsewhere. I think it should be something like `lapply(my_list, function(df) filter(df, grepl("blank", ROI)) %>% ... )` where the `...` is the means you want to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close. Your code references `mylist` which (according to your code) does not exist. Further, `my_list$ROI` also does not exist, since `my_list` is an unnamed list. What you want (I think) is the `$ROI` column of *each element of the list of data.frames*.

Your call to `lapply` looks clean by not requiring an anonymous function, but I suggest you either define your own `filter` function or just use an anon-func here:

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) filter(x, grepl("blank", ROI)))
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 3
#     ROI   Red Green
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 blank   1.9   1.1
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#      ROI   Red Green
#    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 blank1   0.5     2
# 2 blank2   0.7     7
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I edited so it is `my_list` now through my post. You are correct about _each element of the list of data.frames_ too. I will check `lapply`  now as you suggested. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I cannot believe this was much easier than I thought. You are awesome!